# How to have nested conditions for PMD Xpath rules

Tags: xpath, pmd

My rule requires me to apply them only to methods without 'get' as part of their name. In another words, my rules need to apply to only non-getter methods in the class. I know to get a hold of all the non-getter methods, I can use

```
//MethodDeclarator[not(contains(@Image,'get'))]
```

However, I don't know the syntax about where I insert my logic for the rules. Is it like

```
//MethodDeclarator[
not(contains(@Image,'get'))

 'Some Rule Statements' 
]
```

I saw the use of . in the beginning of statement inside [] in some example code. what are they used for?

In my particular case, I need to combine following pieces together but so far I am unable to accomplish it yet.

Piece 1:

```
 //PrimaryExpression[not(PrimarySuffix/Arguments)]
```

Piece 2:

```
 //MethodDeclarator[not(contains(@Image,'get'))]
```

Piece 3:

```
 //PrimaryExpression[PrimaryPrefix/@Label='this']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to have at least some basic knowledge/understanding of XPath**.

> I saw the use of `.` in the beginning of statement inside [] in some
>   example code. what are they used for?

`[]` is called *predicate*. It must contain a boolean expression. It must immediately follow a node-test. This specifies an additional condition for a node that satisfies the node-test to be selected.

**For example**:

```
/*/num
```

selects all elements named `num` that are children of the top element of the XML document.

However, if we want to select only such `num` elements, whose value is an odd integer, we add this additional condition inside a predicate:

```
/*/num[. mod 2 = 1]
```

Now this last expression selects all elements named `num` that are children of the top element of the XML document *and* whose string value represents an odd integer.

`.`  denotes the *context node* -- this is the node that has been selected so-far (or the starting node off which the complete XPath expression is evaluated).

> In my particular case, I need to combine following pieces together ...

You forgot to say in what way / how the three expressions should be combined. In XPath some of the frequently used "combinators" are the operators `and`, `or`, and the function `not()`.

For example, if you want to select elements that are selected by *all* three provided XPath expressions, you can use the `and` operator:

```
//PrimaryExpression
   [not(PrimarySuffix/Arguments)
  and
    PrimaryPrefix/@Label='this'
   ]
```

Comment: I read more about XPath this morning and made them combined properly now. I also realize that the AST in PMD was more deceiving than the XML. It is much more sensible to look at the RAW xml and trace it using XPath than following the examples in PMD doc. I had trouble knowing when to use /Name and @Image because I didn't realize their place in the XML.

Comment: @ttback: Yes, I was going to point out that you need more than XPath to know the semantics of PMD.

Comment: Yea, I've come very close to be able to find one node in a node-set. If you want to, you can check on my latest question. Without Intersect and knowledge of how to use axis, it is getting very annoying to know whether I'm working with the node-set that I think I'm working with.